# Java unresolved JPanel variable?

Tags: java, eclipse

Why can't `aniPanel` be resolved to a variable. I've tried

```
AniPanel aniPanel = new AniPanel();
```

but this doesn't solve the problem. I've also made sure to

import java.swing.JPanel

This is the class:

```
public class Animation {

    public JPanel AniPanel;

    private boolean loop = true;

    private RenderingHints renderingHints = new RenderingHints(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

     @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class AniPanel extends JPanel {

            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setRenderingHints(renderingHints);
                draw(g2d);
            }
        }

     public static void main(String[] args){

        Circle C = new Circle(100);

        JFrame jf = new JFrame();

        jf.setTitle("Falling Shapes Animation");
        jf.setSize(600,400);

        aniPanel = new AniPanel();
        jf.getContentPane().add(aniPanel);

        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.pack();

    }
```

Comment: `AniPanel` class and field must be static if you want static access

Answer (score 1):

There are various things wrong with your code.

Firstly, Java is case-sensitive. Here's your variable declaration:

```
public JPanel AniPanel;
```

And here's where you're trying to use it:

```
aniPanel = new AniPanel();
```

Note the capital `A` in the declaration. Additionally, you're trying to use it from a *static* method, so you either need to specify an instance for it, or you make it a static variable. It should be:

```
public static JPanel aniPanel;
```

... or preferrably:

```
private static JPanel aniPanel;
```

Even better, make it a *local* variable instead of a field - you only ever use it in `main` anyway. So just remove the current declaration and then use:

```
AniPanel aniPanel = new AniPanel();
```

You'll *then* have the problem that it's an inner class, which means you need an instance of `Animation` in order to create an instance of `AniPanel`. You can fix that by either making `AniPanel` a static nested class, or by removing it from within `Animation` (making it a top-level class). Personally I'd recommend avoiding nested classes where possible - particularly if you're relatively new to Java. You should remove the `loop` variable entirely (you never use it) and move `renderingHints` into `AniPanel`.